# DryIOC equivalent of Unity's PerResolveLifetimeManager

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, dryioc

How to simulate Unity's `PerResolveLifetimeManager` with DryIoc?

That is, reuse within the current call to resolve, but not otherwise:

```
var a = container.Resolve<A>();
Assert( ReferenceEquals(a.B.D, a.C.D ) );

var a2 = container.Resolve<A>();
Assert( !ReferenceEquals(a.B.D, a2.B.D ) );
```

with

```
class A 
{
    public B B {get;}
    public C C {get;}
}

class B
{
    public D D {get;}
}

class C
{
    public D D {get;}
}
```

With Unity, I'd register `D` with a `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, but I've got no idea how to achieve that with DryIoc.

In my application, `A` might be a top-level view model and `D` an Entity Framework context: whenever I navigate (i.e. resolve a new view model), I want to create a new context to be used while this view model is active, and I want it to be shared by all dependencies that view model might have.

Comment: Can you update your question and express why you need this and why the usual `Scoped` lifestyle wouldn't work for you?

Comment: I want an implicit scope without having to manually open one. `PerResolveLifetimeManager` provides an automatic unit-of-work (per view model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [doc](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/ReuseAndScopes.md#reusescopedto-service-type) and the example below:

```cs
container.Register<A>(setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true));

container.Register<B>(Reuse.ScopedTo<A>());
container.Register<D>(Reuse.ScopedTo<A>());

var a = container.Resolve<A>();
Assert( ReferenceEquals(a.B.D, a.C.D ) );

var a2 = container.Resolve<A>();
Assert( !ReferenceEquals(a.B.D, a2.B.D ) );
```

Comment: Actually, I've stumbled across `Reuse.ScopedTo<>` and I thought was meant to scope to a _concrete_ type, here `A`. I need to scope to _any_ view model that's resolved. Does `ScopedTo<BaseType>` automatically scope to all types derived from `BaseType`, for example?

Comment: @haukinger Here is the exempt from the doc:
*You may match not only the exact TService but its base class or the implemented interface.*